# A variable of which a part is variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, dynamic

I have variables that look something like this:

```
$INFOMonday
$INFOTuesday
```

In my Bash script, I would like to use the value of todays variable, so to say. I extracted the day with:

```
dayofweek=$(date --date=${dateinfile#?_} "+%A")
```

What I need help with, is doing the following:

```
echo $INFO$dayofweek
```

Is there any way of adding a variable as part of a variables name? For example, if it's monday, the echo would return the value of $INFOMonday.

Comment: Why not use an associative array instead?

Comment: @mbratch That would only work for mondays. I want the second part to be variable.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old-style way of doing this is with the indirection operator `${!variable}`:

```
dayofweek=$(date...)
var=INFO$dayofweek
echo ${!var}
```

Note that in `${!var}`, `var` must be a variable-name, not a string expression or other type of substitution. It's a little clunky.

The newer way of doing it would be with an [associative array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays).

Comment: Thank you very much. Works fine. I'll take a look at associative arrays too.